# selenium как взять значение у элемента background-image

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

есть вот такой код html

```
  <div loading="lazy" class="gallery__picture" style="background-image: url("ссылка на фото");"><!----></div>
```

и мне нужно найти значение  url y background-image

```
 img = driver.find_elements(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value='gallery__picture')
  
  for i in img:
    print(i.get_attribute('style'))
```

как я могу это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Таким способом мы получаем   background-image

```
   img = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "gallery__picture"))).value_of_css_property("background-image")
```

> на выходе мы получаем url('Ссылку')
>
> чтобы убрать url и скобки

```
img = re.split('[()]',img)[1]
```